# Linking Boost to my C++ project in Eclipse

Tags: c++, regex, eclipse, boost, linker

I'm trying to get the Boost library working in my C++ projects in Eclipse. I can successfully build when using header-only libraries in Boost such as the example simple program in the "Getting Started" guide using the lambda header.

I cannot get my project to successfully link to the regex Boost library as shown later in the guide. Under my project properties -> c/c++ build -> settings -> tool settings tab -> libraries, I have added "libboost_regex" to the Libraries box, and "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_42_0\bin.v2\libs" to the Library search path box since this is where all the .lib files are. I've even tried adding "libboost_regex-mgw34-mt-d-1_42.lib" to the libraries box instead of "libboost_regex" since that is the exact file name, but this did not work either.

I keep getting an error that says "cannot find -llibboost_regex" when I try to build my project. Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

**Edit**: on Windows XP, using mingw, and I have tried "boost_regex" as well..

Comment: Shouldn't it be -lboost_regex?

Comment: What platform are you on? What compiler/linker are you using?

Comment: Yes I built boost using bjam as described in the getting started guide. I know this worked since the .lib are now present. For example the regex file is in C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_42_0\bin.v2\libs\regex\build\gcc-mingw-3.4.2\debug\link-static\threading-multi, similarly there is a release folder as well as the debug folder

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just went through the whole process of installing MinGW, compiling boost and installing Eclipse CDT and I'm able to compile simple programs using `boost:regex`. I'll write down all the steps. I hope that can be of help.

I've installed MinGW and MSYS in their default location.

Here are the step I took to build boost:

- Download boost-jam-3.1.18-1-ntx86.zip from http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-jam
- Put bjam.exe somewhere in your PATH
- Unpack boost in `C:\mingw\boost_1_42_0`
- Open an msys terminal window and `cd /c/mingw/boost_1_42_0`
- In the boost directory run `bjam --build-dir=build toolset=gcc stage`

To configure Eclipse:

- Add CDT to Eclipse 3.5 from [the update site](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/galileo)
- Create a new C++ project
- Under the *Project* menu select *properties*
- Make sure the configuration is *Debug [Active]*
- In "*C/C++ General*" > "*Paths and Symbols*"

  - Under the *Includes* tab select the *GNU C++* language and add `C:\MinGW\boost_1_42_0`
  - Under the *Library Paths* tab add `C:\MinGW\boost_1_42_0\stage\lib`
- In "*C/C++ Build*" > "*Settings*"

  - Select *MinGW C++ Linker* > *Libraries*
  - Click on the add button for *Libraries (-l)*
  - Type `libboost_regex-mgw34-mt-d` *(without the .lib)*

You can then go through the same steps for the *Release* configuration but use `libboost_regex-mgw34-mt` instead. Also make sure your source files include `<boost/regex.hpp>`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I changed the library paths directory to the stage\lib directory and added the libboost_regex-mgw34-mt-d and it worked!

Comment: I found the step-by-step on this very helpful for the eclipse side. I had to use it in combination with this other question to help me through the most current directory structure and build process for boost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299468/unable-to-build-boost-libraries-with-gcc (The answer is 7 yrs old, so no complaint.  Just an update!)

Answer (score 7):

To link to boost library in eclipse you need to set both the eclipse's project library path(the one with the -L) and the name of the library(the one with the -l).

The prefix 'lib' and the extension of the library's name must be removed:- 
  eg: libboost_regex.a should be specified as boost_regex.

Comment: Thanks! I was having a nghtmare on mac os x with this. Ended up just entering "boost_system" for the -l and my -L pointing to "bin.v2/libs".

Comment: this should be the right answer. it solves the problem on all operating systems and is version independent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your lib path is pointing to the wrong place. The libs will be installed to:

boost_install_dir\boost_1_42\lib

I think the default boost_install_dir is "C:\Program Files\Boost" (not sure because I don't use the default install directory).

Comment: I have a "libs" directory, but not "lib" in my boost directory, but this does not actually contain the compiled files which are in the bin.v2\libs directory