# build boost with mingw from QtSDK

Tags: c++, qt, boost, mingw

I'd like to use boost with QtCreator. I'm using Windows 7 and installed the QtSDK wich ship's with mingw. When I execute `bootstrap.bat` I get the following error

```
C:\boost\boost_1_49_0>bootstrap
Building Boost.Build engine
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
Please consult bootstrap.log for furter diagnostics.

You can try to obtain a prebuilt binary from

   http://sf.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=72941

Also, you can file an issue at http://svn.boost.org
Please attach bootstrap.log in that case.
```

The bootstrap.log contains the following

```
###
### Using 'msvc' toolset.
###

C:\boost\boost_1_49_0\tools\build\v2\engine>if exist bootstrap rd /S /Q bootstrap 

C:\boost\boost_1_49_0\tools\build\v2\engine>md bootstrap 

C:\boost\boost_1_49_0\tools\build\v2\engine>cl /nologo /GZ /Zi /MLd /Fobootstrap/ /Fdbootstrap/ -DNT -DYYDEBUG kernel32.lib advapi32.lib user32.lib /Febootstrap\jam0  command.c compile.c debug.c execnt.c expand.c filent.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c newstr.c option.c output.c parse.c pathunix.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c md5.c pwd.c class.c w32_getreg.c native.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.cmodules/sequence.c modules/order.c
```

My first guess would be that boost tries to build with MSVC instead of mingw, but I have no idea how to change that behaviour. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299468/unable-to-build-boost-libraries-with-gcc), I tried `bootstrap.bat gcc` which resulted in an error because gcc wasn't found. A short look at the `path` environment variable showed that the path to `QtSDK\mingw\bin` was missing, because the QtSDK didn't add it.

The solution was simply

```
path = %PATH%;C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin
bootstrap.bat gcc
.\b2 --toolset=gcc
```