# Boost library eclipse linking error

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

I'm working on windows 7 and eclipse juno. In my project i have linked correctly header-only boost libraries, and i need only two compiled libs ("libboost_signals-mgw46-mt-1_54.a" and "libboost_signals-mgw46-mt-d-1_54.a"). I added them to the MinGW C++ linker in the same way is explained here [Linking Boost to my C++ project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519727/linking-boost-to-my-c-project-in-eclipse). The path i have specified in "Library search path" for the linker is "C:\MinGW\boost_1_54_0\stage\lib" (where compiled libraries reside) and the libraries themselves are added with their names except the ".a". But when i try to build the project i get this error:

Info: Internal Builder is used for build
   g++ "-LC:\MinGW\boost_1_54_0\boost" -o Ccccc.exe "src\Ccccc.o" -llibboost_signals-         mgw46-mt-1_54 -llibboost_signals-mgw46-mt-d-1_54 
   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -  llibboost_signals-mgw46-mt-1_54
   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibboost_signals-mgw46-mt-d-1_54
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

The code is irrelevant because in order to solve this problem i try to add those libraries to a simply "Hello world" project. Thanks for any help, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a wild guess but try omitting the **lib** from the library name to see if it can find the library that way.  Otherwise, clearly the library cannot be found in your library path.

Comment: Great!  MingW uses the convention to try and find things by lib<name>.dll among some other patterns.  Keep that in mind.  If my answer helped you please upvote and accept the answer :).

Comment: Thank you, of course i accept the answer but i had to wait 7 minutes to accepte it, now you got it ;)